# On Mac, how to open a file from command line and have it shown in an existing Emacs window?

Tags: command-line, emacs

How to open a file from command line and have it shown in one of the existing windows in the existing frame, otherwise in a new window in a new frame?  The default behavior is it is opened in a new frame.  I'm using

> GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0) of 2012-01-29 on beta.macosforge.org

### Edit 1

I didn't pay enough attention to my aliases definition.  I'm using

```
alias emacs=open -a /Applications/Macports/Emacs.app
```

in my `.bashrc`.  With this setting, if there is an existing Emacs frame I opened earlier, when a new emacs is run from command line (`$ emacs foobar.txt`), it opens a new frame, and even loads .emacs for it, and then displays the file in one of the windows of the new frame. (My `.emacs` setting automatically split the frame into two windows.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify exactly how you're opening a file from the command line, but the default behavior for `emacsclient` is in fact the opposite: it re-uses a frame. From the [`emacsclient` documentation at gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html#emacsclient-Options), the `-c` option is used to get the behavior you seem to have by default.

> **`-c`** Create a new graphical frame, instead of using an existing Emacs frame. Emacs 23 can create a graphical frame even if it was started in a text-only terminal, provided it is able to connect to a graphical display. If no graphical display is available, Emacs creates a new text-only terminal frame (see Frames). If you omit a filename argument while supplying the ‘-c’ option, the new frame displays the ‘*scratch*’ buffer (see Buffers).

I can confirm that's how it works on my system, which is few revs behind: `GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.29) of 2010-05-08 on black.local"`

I'd check to make sure you're using the `emacsclient` that shipped with your emacs, and that you aren't inadvertently sending `-c`.

Comment: It turns out I aliased `emacs` with `alias emacs=open -a /Applications/Macports/Emacs.app`.  But still, if there is an existing Emacs frame, when a new `emacs` is run from command line, it opens a new frame, and even loads `.emacs` with it.

Comment: @Computist, in fact, when you use that alias. You start a *new* Emacs, it does not open a new frame in the running Emacs. I would recommend using "emacsclient".

Comment: @Lindydancer, do you have more specific suggestion as to how my alias might be modified to use `emacsclient`?

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
emacs() {
/Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient --alternate-editor=/Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs $1 &
}
```

It uses emacsclient to open the file you specified - if it doesn't find an existing Emacs server, it opens a new one.

In .emacs, do

```
(server-start)
```

so that starting emacs also starts a server.